# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress could not load custom certificate from cert-manager

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I am using `cert-manager` with this custom wildcard certificate:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-myapp-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: app@example.com # CHANGE-ME
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: wildcard-myapp-com
    solvers:
      # ACME DNS-01 provider configurations
      - dns01:
          cloudDNS:
            serviceAccountSecretRef:
              name: clouddns-service-account
              key: dns-service-account.json
            project: myapp
        selector:
          dnsNames:
            - '*.myapp.com'
            - myapp.com
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: myapp-com-tls
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: myapp-com-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-myapp-issuer
  commonName: '*.myapp.com'
  dnsNames:
    - '*.myapp.com'
    - myapp.com
```

I am deploying Nginx ingress with kustomize:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: controller
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
        - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
        - --ingress-class=nginx
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --validating-webhook=:8443
        - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
        - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
        - --default-ssl-certificate=default/myapp-com-tls # NOTE THIS LINE
```

When I open the logs of the ingress controller, I could see this error:

> Error loading custom default certificate, falling back to generate ││ local SSL certificate default/myapp-com-tls was not found

What I can do to troubleshoot this?

```
$ kubectl describe certificates myapp-com-tls -n cert-manager
Error from server (NotFound): certificates.cert-manager.io "myapp-com-tls" not found
```

Comment: Your ClusterIssuer's name is letsencrypt-mywoocart-issuer but your Certificate's issuerRef.name is letsencrypt-myapp-issuer.  Is this intentional?

Comment: It was a mistake, fixed

Comment: Assuming it's still not working, is a status block being generated for either resource?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine, but without the wildcard certificate issued by cert-manager